# Add right click item in ms word using Windows Application vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, windows

Iam Using VS 2010 , i want to add Add right click item in ms word using vb.net.

I dont have this Event Handler

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

End Sub
```

i tried this but not working

```
Dim cellbar As Office.CommandBar = Doc.Application.CommandBars("Cell")
Dim button As Office.CommandBarButton = DirectCast(cellbar.FindControl(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 0, "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU"), Office.CommandBarButton)
If button Is Nothing Then
button = DirectCast(cellbar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, , , cellbar.Controls.Count, True), Office.CommandBarButton)
button.Caption = "Refresh"
button.BeginGroup = True
button.Tag = "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU"
End If
```

Experts,Please give me suggestions to get a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157876.aspx to add

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
End Sub
```

to your project. you need to import classes to access such methodes